# Transition pixel to percent

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like do a transition using CSS, but my element's dimensions are in pixels normally but in percent during the `:hover` event, and the transition doesn't work like this. Do you know any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to use JavaScript to change the percentage value to pixels after it has been calculated. I think webkit reports dimensions in px regardless of how they were set when called via JavaScript.

Answer (score 16):

You can apply the transition on the **% width** and just use **min-width** as px fixed value.

```
.elem {
    min-width:50px; /* min-width as the pixel value */ 
    width:0%; /* width as the % value */ 
    transition:width .8s ease; /* transition applied to width */
}
.apply-new-width {
    width:100% !important;
}
```

Be carefull **min-width** is stronger than **width**. So when you'll apply the new width (in %) min-width will still override it. You have several options to handle this : increase the .apply-new-width [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) (eg: .elem.apply-new-width or div.apply-new-width) or use the !important rule. Usually !important is a bad solution but here it does the trick.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkneb/judNR/) of a working exemple. It works in all browsers, except of course in IE where transitions are not supported, but it gracefully degrades so we can say it works every where :)

Cheers

Comment: This is a great idea. Building off of it -- why not just animate the min-width value? Then there's no need for using `!important`. Here is my edit of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/judNR/7/

Answer (score 4):

It works just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/eCxQP/

Normal width - in pixels, hover - in percent

```
body {
     width: 100%;
 }


 div  {
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     background:red;
     transition:width 2s;
     -moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
     -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
     -o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
 }

 div:hover {
     width:33%;
 }
```

UPDATE: works in FF, not the Webkit based browsers

Answer (score 3):

I works fine on Firefox but not on Chromium for which you need to use the same unit.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old but if your support is IE9 and above you can do something like this...

In Css

```
div{ width:100%; transition: width .2s ease;}
div.set-px-width { width: calc(0% + 50px); }
```

In JS

```
div.className += "set-px-width"
```

The above would transition from 100% width to 50px width by using the calc with a percent of 0. This seems to still treat the width as percent and will transition appropriately