# CSS Transition won't happen as expected

Tags: css, css-transitions

```css
.tooltip {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 10s linear all;
  width: 100px;
}
.tooltip:after,
.tooltip:before {
  transition: 10s linear all
}
.tooltip:before {
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  right: 50000px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -12px
}
.tooltip:after {
  background: #FCE0BA;
  top: 100%;
  right: 50000px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 100px
}
.tooltip:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #FCE0BA transparent;
  border-width: 0px 6px 12px 6px;
  content: "";
  right: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px
}
.tooltip:hover:after {
  background: #FCE0BA;
  color: #559bd9;
  content: attr(title);
  right: 20%;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  max-height: 999999px
}
```

```html
<span class="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum!">Hover me</div>
```

I am trying to create a transition for the right position,

As you can see, it has a very large right value, and then the one i need,

But for some reason, the transition won't animate,

Do you know what i am missing?

Comment: only a few browsers support transition for pseudo-elements, also, you should order shorthand of transition as it have to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because your `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements don't contain `content:""` before `:hover`  occurs. You can't animate something if it never showed up.

I also changed `transition: 10s linear all` to `transition: all 10s linear`, as this is [the correct shorthand syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property) for `transition`.

Now the transition occurs really quickly, due to the extremely high `right:50000px` set, it travels a looooong time in this 10 seconds (barely noticeable). - I changed this to a lower amount.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39q2pc04/) - *note that the animation is really terrible now, but at least made it to work. You should still have to change it the way you desire, but it's showing that it works now.*

Answer (score 0):

For CSS transitions to work, the values being transition to and from need to be either both lengths or percentages (or calc()). See [this section](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#animatable-css) in the W3C CSS Transitions doc.

> The animated value is interpolated from the from and to values when both the from and the to values of the property have the type described. (When a composite type such as "length, percentage, or calc" is listed, this means that both values must fit into that composite type.) When multiple types are listed in the form "either A or B", both values must be of the same type to be interpolable.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, a few problems. I didn't finish figuring out why, but if you inspect element before you hover, there is no :before and :after even visible. So step 1 is cleaning up your CSS. Only 1 property is changing on hover, and that's the right value. So when you declare your `.tooltip:hover:before`, there should only be one property in that: the changed right value.

Problem #2 is that you can't go from px to % in a transition. Transitions only effect numbers of same values. So here's what I did instead:

First, build your tooltip as :before and :after the way you want it to appear on hover. Then once it looks good, change your right: values to where the start point of your animation will be. Then you set the :hover:before and :hover:after just to the right values. See below.

Problem 3: your distance and time span for animation were both unusually long. I know you wanted it to be not visible and slide in from the left, so let's solve that with some practical animations. By targetting which properties are animated, we can make this look pretty nice.

```css
.tooltip {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 10s linear all;
  width: 100px;
}
.tooltip:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #FCE0BA transparent;
  border-width: 0px 6px 12px 6px;
  content: "";
  margin-top: -12px;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -12px
}
.tooltip:after {
  background: #FCE0BA;
  color: #559bd9;
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  max-height: 999999px;
  background: #FCE0BA;
  top: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 100px
}
.tooltip:hover:before {
  right: 50%;
  opacity:1;
}
.tooltip:hover:after {
  right: 20%;
  opacity:1;
}
.tooltip:after,
.tooltip:before {
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity:0;
  right:100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum!">Hover me</div>
```

Comment: This answer covers up a lot of the same stuff as in my answer, only thing you did else was provide an animation of better quality. Also, you're providing false information as [you can actually transition from px to %](http://jsfiddle.net/upzy1u50/).

Comment: @DaanHeskes would the `px` to `%` bit work cross browser? I ask because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975538/transition-pixel-to-percent appears to suggest it works in FF but not in webkit.

Comment: Tested it and can confirm it works on at least FireFox, Chrome and IE. @DavidT

Comment: @DaanHeskes ok great, ill remove my comment from the OP question as it would appear this is incorrect then. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: That was suggested on January 2012. It'd be a questionable move for IE and Chrome if they didn't want to catch up with FireFox on something that useful in a time span of 3 and a half year, right? :) @DavidT

Comment: @DaanHeskes ok so maybe i should look at the dates of questions a little more closely :) long day.

Comment: @DaanHeskes - I think if you look at the time stamps on our replies, differing by less than 5 minutes, you can see that I wasn't copying your answer, but working on mine still while you posted yours.

Comment: @DaanHeskes And while % to px may work in browsers, that's not actually part of spec as Emily posted in another answer.